# pandas random shuffling dataframe with constraints

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe that I need to randomise in a very specific way with a particular rule, and I'm a bit lost. A simplified version is here:

```
idx type    time
1   a   1
2   a   1
3   a   1
4   b   2
5   b   2
6   b   2
7   a   3
8   a   3
9   a   3
10  b   4
11  b   4
12  b   4
13  a   5
14  a   5
15  a   5
16  b   6
17  b   6
18  b   6
19  a   7
20  a   7
21  a   7
```

If we consider this as containing seven "bunches", I'd like to randomly shuffle by those bunches, i.e. retaining the time column. However, the constraint is that after shuffling, a particular bunch type (`a` or `b` in this case) cannot appear more than n (e.g. 2) times in a row. So an example correct result looks like this:

```
idx type    time
21  a   7
20  a   7
19  a   7
7   a   3
8   a   3
9   a   3
17  b   6
16  b   6
18  b   6
6   b   2
5   b   2
4   b   2
2   a   1
3   a   1
1   a   1
14  a   5
13  a   5
15  a   5
12  b   4
11  b   4
10  b   4
```

I was thinking I could create a separate "order" array from 1 to 7 and `np.random.shuffle()` it, then sort the dataframe by `time` in that order, which will probably work - I can think of ways to do that part, but I'm especially struggling with the rule of restricting the number of repeats.

I know roughly that I should use a while loop, shuffle it in that way, loop over the frame and track the number of consecutive `type`s, if it exceeds my n then break out and start the while loop again until it completes without breaking out, in which case set a value to end the while loop. But this got so messy and didn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

See if this works.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np


n = [['a',1],['a',1],['a',1],
     ['b',2],['b',2],['b',2],
     ['a',3],['a',3],['a',3]]
df = pd.DataFrame(n)
df.columns = ['type','time']
print(df)

order = np.unique(np.array(df['time']))
print("Before Shuffling",order)
np.random.shuffle(order)
print("Shuffled",order)

n =2
for i in order:
    print(df[df['time']==i].iloc[0:n])
```